# Xcode 10 how to use new build system with obfuscator-llvm plugin

Tags: ios, xcode, llvm, llvm-clang, xcode10

I follow tutorial from [integration-into-xcode](https://github.com/obfuscator-llvm/obfuscator/wiki/Installation#integration-into-xcode), it worked for Xcode 9, In Xcode 10, Select File -> Project/Workspace Setting, there is a Build System option, the new build system is selected as default, with this default setting, the clang path is always set as `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang`, the value of `ExecPath` from Obfuscator.xcspec file is not respected, how can I make it work with new build system?

Comment: did you figure this out? I'm battling with this as well.

Comment: @pechar, no I haven't, have to keep using old build system.

Comment: I've been looking into https://github.com/HikariObfuscator/Hanabi but unfortunately it doesn't seem to be working either. The commands are definitely running as when I mistyped certain parameters it failed to compile but the result is the same binary when I check it with `nm`

Answer (score 0):

It seems that XCode10 does not handle the `ExecPath` key anymore.

One possible solution is to **override `CC`, `LD`, and `AR`** to achieve a similar result. This can be done in two different ways:

- within the plugin, for instance by creating a new compiler option named `CC`.
- As a "User-Defined Setting" in the build settings window or your project/target. Just create a setting named `CC` and set it to the value you would have put in the `ExecPath` key.

Both solutions rely on the same mechanism. If defined, these variables are used in place of the selected toolchain. These are empty by default. However, according to my test, this was a bit different in previous versions of XCode where the variable were first resolved by XCode (I believe using *whereis*). e.g. defining `CC=echo`, XCode9 compiles with `/bin/echo` while XCode10 compiles with `echo`. If the executable cannot be found by XCode9, this may result in a freeze on an *indexing* task.

Answer (score -1):

From Xcode7-ish onwards you could directly use a toolchain